# How to sculpt along a specific axis?

Tags: sculpting, axis

I have faced a problem in sculpting: When trying to grab, sculpt result ends up traveling along the X or Y axis while trying to be pulled down Z axis.

Is there I can set Blender to sculpt along the Z axis, or another single axis, so that I can sculpt better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some brushes have this option in their properties panel, but the grab brush doesn't seem to follow its instructions, and it seems to be always view-related.

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug that needs to be reported?

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while you are using grab brush, it will grab along the first vertex normal plane.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old so not sure if still helpful to answer, but if you go into Tool, then Advanced, you will see "Sculpt Plane".

This can be set to Area, View, X Plane, Y Plane or Z Plane.

[image]

This will lock the movement of vertices to that particular plane. I'm using Z plane to sculpt a terrain whilst keeping the X/Y resolution consistent, for example.